# How should I use a guard statement correctly with RxSwift Singles?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

Imagine I have a networking client, using `RxSwift` to wrap `URLSession`.

I'd like to use a `guard` statement and return an error, however I am getting an error that

> Non-void function should return a value

Which makes sense, however I am unsure how to handle this with `RxSwift`.

```
class NetworkClient {
    var task: URLSessionDataTask = URLSessionDataTask()
    var session: SessionProtocol = URLSession.shared
    var request: URLRequest?

    func call<T: Codable>(_ request: URLRequest) -> Single<T> {
        return Single<T>.create(subscribe: { [weak self] observer -> Disposable in
            guard let `self` = self else { observer(.error(NSError(domain: "", code: 0, userInfo: [:]))); return }
            self.task = self.session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

            })


            return Disposables.create {
                self.task.cancel()
            }
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: Side note: `observer(.error(NSError(domain: "", code: 0, userInfo: [:]))` I would *really* hate it if I encountered an error with no message, code or user info.

Comment: Of course, I just through together a very simple example that would compile. That is by no means an error I would ever return in any application :)

Comment: Okay, just checking :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use:

```
guard let `self` = self else { observer(.error(NSError(domain: "", code: 0, userInfo: [:]))); return Disposables.create() }
```

However, I have to say I'm not a fan of the class at all. First, RxSwift already has a wrapper around dataTask:

```
func response(request: URLRequest) -> Observable<(response: HTTPURLResponse, data: Data)>
```

which can be called by:

```
URLSession.shared.rx.response(request: myRequest)
```

There's also `data(request:)` which will check the statusCode and emit an error if it's not in the 200's.

You can simply inject the function instead of adding the complexity of wrapping it in an object that provides no value add. For example:

```
struct MyViewModel {
    init(serverResponse: @escaping (URLRequest) -> Observable<Data>)...
}
```

Which can be called by:

```
let myViewModel = MyViewModel(serverResponse: URLSession.shared.rx.data)
```

In testing, you can simply pass a closure that returns `Observable<Data>.just(myTestData)`.

Comment: Thank you so much, for all your comments. I very much appreciate you taking the time to share your thoughts also, they have been incredibly helpful.

Comment: Nice, Do you have a blog, Daniel?

Comment: https://medium.com/@danielt1263 I also have a some sample projects: https://github.com/danielt1263/RxMyCoordinator https://github.com/danielt1263/RxEarthquake https://github.com/danielt1263/RxMultiCounter